# Error in PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql

I am new to SQL. Whenever I try to execute the following code, it gives MySQLSyntaxErrorException. Please Help!!

```
    Connection Conn_Save = null;
        PreparedStatement Pst_Save = null;
        Conn_Save = MysqlConnect.ConnectDB();
        String UserName = "pv";
        String CreateSql = "Create table if not exists ? (Col_Date Date, Col_Break Varchar(20),Col_Lun Varchar(20),Col_Snack Varchar(20),Col_Dine Varchar(20))";
        Pst_Save = Conn_Save.prepareStatement(CreateSql);
        Pst_Save.setString(1, UserName);
        Pst_Save.execute();
```

Comment: What is the error message

Comment: You can not use plcaeholder for tables names

Comment: You want to create a new table for every user? That's not generally how SQL databases work. The database schema (the table definitions) are static. The *data* is dynamic. Create a single table, add a `UserName` column and always query with `where UserName = ?`.

Comment: And ehhh.... prefixing all your columns with `Col_` is redundant. Columns exist in their own namespace, so their names will not clash with anything else.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jens and Andreas.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid the database doesn't work like this -when you prepare an sql statement the structure of the statement must be there (specifically you need to specify the tables, columns etc up front - only the DATA can be assigned using place holders).

This restriction is logical as the DBMS has to parse the SQL at prepare-time in order to build an optimized query.

If you want to achieve what you are trying you have to build a dynamic sql string with the parameterised table included in the string for each new table. Then just use a normal execute on it.